# Weird proof with matrix determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, proof-explanation

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b \in \Bbb R^4$ and $t \in \Bbb R$.

Show that

$$\frac{d}{dt} \det(a_1, a_2 + tb, a_3, a_4) = \det(a_1, b, a_3, a_4)$$

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this.
How can you derive a determinant?

Comment: Firstly, before anything, go here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Use the multilinearity of the determinant, which you probably have seen in your course.

Comment: hmm... actually everyone who post question here are expected to type in mathjax... and the earlier you pick it up, the more benefits you will get from the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get you started:\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \det\begin{bmatrix}  a_1 , a_2+tb,a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix} &=\frac{d}{dt} \det\begin{bmatrix}  a_1 , a_2,a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix} + \frac{d}{dt} \det\begin{bmatrix}  a_1 , tb,a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \frac{d}{dt}\det \begin{bmatrix}  a_1 , tb,a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}

Note that $\det \begin{bmatrix}  a_1 , tb,a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix}$ is linear in $t$.

Edit:

Note that $$\det\begin{bmatrix} a_1, bt, a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix}=t\det\begin{bmatrix} a_1, b, a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I added one more line. can you differentiate that expression with respect to $t$?

Comment: then it becomes $\det \begin{bmatrix}  a_1 , b,a_3, a_4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: yup, the whole proof is based on properties of determinant.

Comment: thanks so much for the help!